# Python Built in f(x) size of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, built-in

I'm struggling with writing a script that returns the total amount of arguments that are given for the function, the arguments can be either a string, tuple, list or a mapping dictionary. In the script below the test sample only returns 3 when the problem is requesting to count every single argument so id like it to return 7. Any explanation or help is greatly appreciated!

'''Return the length (the number of items) of a sequence 
(string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).'''

Write a function that returns the total size of the arguments.

Note: *args denotes a variable argument list, represented by a tuple.

```
def totSize(*args): 
    return len(args)
print(totSize('abc', (1,), [1,2,3]))
```

3

Comment: The function "isinstance" allows to check the type of an object. Depending on the type you can the object then ask for a length or not.

Comment: `return sum(len(arg) for arg in args)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro that only works for iterable types, but fails if say an integer is passed into args.

Comment: @L.MacKenzie "the arguments can be either a string, tuple, list or a mapping dictionary."

Comment: @L.MacKenzie I know - but the question is only asking about sequences/mappings. It makes no sense to try to get the length other types.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that you want to get length of all arguments and add the lengths together.

Here is the code:

```
def totSize(*args):
    return sum(map(len, args))
```

This code first maps len on all arguments `['abc', (1,), [1, 2, 3]]` becomes `[3, 1, 3]` and than sums them. Note that this code assumes, that all argumens can be passed to `len`

Comment: This also fails if an integer is passed in as an argument. You should check that the argument is iterable before trying to use len.

Comment: Yes, from the question part `''Return the length (the number of items) of a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).'''` i deduced, that only string, tuple, list and dict can be passed to the function

Answer (score 2):

This solution is more general as it works for any object that can be passed to `len` as well as simple objects like `int` or `float`s

```
def totSize(*args):

    total_length = 0
    for arg in args:
        try:
            total_length += len(arg)
        except TypeError:
            total_length += 1
    return total_length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is `Iterable` (`str`, `tuple`, `list`,`dict`, etc..) and accumulate the total size according to it's type (for non iterable elements, like numerics, add 1 to the total size).

For example:

```
from collections import Iterable


def totSize(*args):
    total_size = 0
    for i in args:
        if isinstance(i, Iterable):
            total_size += len(i)
        else:
            total_size += 1
    return total_size


print(totSize('abc', (1,), [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: You can also `from collections import Iterable` and then check `if isinstance(i, Iterable):` instead of listing out a bunch of types.

Comment: @L.MacKenzie Thanks for your comment. I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len` to get the number of items in each arg... sometimes. You also need to cover the case where an argument doesn't have a length

```
>>> def totSize(*args):
...     count = 0
...     for arg in args:
...         try:
...             count += len(arg)
...         except TypeError:
...             count += 1
...     return count
... 
>>> print(totSize('abc', (1,), [1,2,3]))
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Iterable
def totSize(*args):
    return sum(len(x) if isinstance(x, Iterable) else 1 for x in args)
```

(thanks to L. MacKenzie for reminding about `Iterable`)